# Cannot ping VirtualBox VM using bridged network

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, bridge

I have a Fedora 22 laptop with a VirtualBox VM on it. All worked fine when I attached the VM to my wireless network card, but I want to attach it to my hardwired card because the wireless changes. But I cannot ping the VM from my host. Any suggestions?

Here is what I've done:

- Configured my hardwired nic. Set it to not be managed by Networkmanager. I have brought it up, and I can ping it. ifconfig shows:

  ```
  enp0s25: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500`
      inet 10.0.1.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.1.255`
      ether 3c:97:0e:38:c4:9d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
  ```
- Configured my VM with an IP of 10.0.1.100
- Ensured that the VM network device is enabled and attached to "Bridged Adapter", and that it is indeed the hardwired nic.

I start `tcpdump -i enp0s25 -n` on my host. When I ping *out* from my VM- that is, i ping my host's interface using `ping 10.0.1.1`, I get the following on my host:

```
01:11:57.831609 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.1.1 tell 10.0.1.100, length 46
01:11:59.827699 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.1.1 tell 10.0.1.100, length 46
01:12:00.827591 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.1.1 tell 10.0.1.100, length 46
```

the VM says, "Destination host unreachable" (as you would expect when ARP does not reply).

BTW, I checked with Wireshark and I have verified that the incoming arp packet is not VLAN tagged. Just to be sure.

Thanks

Comment: Note that I have no cable connected to my nic. ...I wonder if that's apropros...? Because if I try to ping, Linux will not send out any packet even though the nic is "UP" according to ifconfig.

Answer (score 0):

There was no network cable in the nic. Linux will not send out a network packet if Link detected showed "No".

Comment: Now the question is: Can I create a device for virtual machines only, which won't use a genuine nic, so I can circumvent this issue? I want to be able to travel (== no network connection) and have my network still operate.

Comment: Do a NAT config. Not every places where you connect will give you the necessary IP addresses.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're on to it. I wanted to be able to serve PXE requests from my VM, so I was thinking bridged mode. But I can't have my cake and eat it too. So I'm going to create a host-only network, serve up PXE locally to my other VMs, and add a NATed nic to the VM for connecting to the Internet. Thanks.

Comment: off-topic, are you toying with vagrant? using ansible here.

Comment: No, but thanks for the suggestion. It looks interesting! I'm a salt person myself, we'll see if I can use it with salt.

Comment: Ansible is the equivalent of salt actually. cheers